# Uvloop Bad Installation on Docker

Tags: python, docker, alpine-linux, python-wheel, uvloop

This was an issue when I was building my docker image and experienced a failure when trying to install uvloop in my requirements file

when building a docker image using

```
python:3.10-alpine
```

and using uvloop version

```
uvloop==0.16.0
```

the following will come up

```
#0 61.50       /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_py.py:202: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning:     Installing 'uvloop.handles' as data is deprecated, please list it in `packages`.
#0 61.50           !!
#0 61.50       
#0 61.50       
#0 61.50           ############################
#0 61.50           # Package would be ignored #
#0 61.50           ############################
#0 61.50           Python recognizes 'uvloop.handles' as an importable package,
#0 61.50           but it is not listed in the `packages` configuration of setuptools.
#0 61.50       
#0 61.50           'uvloop.handles' has been automatically added to the distribution only
#0 61.50           because it may contain data files, but this behavior is likely to change
#0 61.50           in future versions of setuptools (and therefore is considered deprecated).
#0 61.50       
#0 61.50           Please make sure that 'uvloop.handles' is included as a package by using
#0 61.50           the `packages` configuration field or the proper discovery methods
#0 61.50           (for example by using `find_namespace_packages(...)`/`find_namespace:`
#0 61.50           instead of `find_packages(...)`/`find:`).
#0 61.50       
#0 61.50           You can read more about "package discovery" and "data files" on setuptools
#0 61.50           documentation page.
#0 61.50       
#0 61.50       
#0 61.50       !!
```

I tried using `pip install -U setuptools pip` inside of the Dockerfile but that doesn't solve the problem.

The way I resolved this issue was to simply update uvloop to
`uvloop==0.17.0`